# how to call REST in a javascript file (NO HTML)

Tags: javascript, rest, get

I have a morris-data.js file that needs to call REST get from a url.

I started with just doing this

```
var json = $.getJSON ('url path');
```

but debug says that $ is not defined.

How do I call REST to get JSON in a native javascript file. (NOT IN HTML)

Comment: Have you added Jquery library to your page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jquery to your code since its morris.js's dependency.  See the following for more information:

http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

Pay close attention "Getting started" section.

Comment: Yes I have everything, but I have a server where I need to get the JSON file for morris data. Which is inside a morris-data.js file. I have to find a way to do REST in the native .js file

Comment: Have taken a look at this: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855